# proving $G(G'G)^{-3/2}G'=(GG')^{-1/2}$

Tags: matrix-calculus

Can someone suggest how this equality is derived? I feel like I'm forgetting some basic property of of matrices (this formula comes up in Figure 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.02958.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the SVD be defined as $\underline {\overline {\bf{G}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } ^ + }$. Then ${\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{G}} } }^ + }\underline {\overline {\bf{G}} } } \right)^{ - \frac{3}{2}}} = \underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } ^{ - 3}}{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } ^ + }$ and the rest should be obvious.

EDIT. $G=U\Lambda V^+$. Then  $(G^+G)^{-3/2}=V\Lambda ^{-3}V^+$

Comment: I think that you have good ideas; unfortunately, your formulae are quasi unreadable and I think that discourages some people from reading you. That's why I'm offering you the above edit.

Comment: @loupblanc: Cool - I use the more tedious notation because I often have problems where there are serious mixtures of scalars, vectors, and matrices, and (to me at least) the visual ability to differentiate the three comes in handy.  But it's probably not for everyone...

Answer (score 1):

I don't like $G$ and $G'$ as notation for matrices, so I'll write $A$ and $B$ instead. So the question is to prove
$$A(BA)^{-3/2}B=(AB)^{-1/2}.\tag{*}$$
If we square the LHS of (*) we get
$$A(BA)^{-3/2}BA(BA)^{-3/2}B=A(BA)^{-2}B=AA^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}B=B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}.$$

So $(*)$ holds if we interpret it as saying that
the expression on the left, whichever
square root of $BA$ we take, when squared gives $(AB)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wonderful result, which I attribute to Higham (but I may be wrong)
$$A\,f(BA) = f(AB)\,A$$
which is true for any two matrices for which the respective function arguments are square-shaped and the functions exists.

Applying this to the current problem yields
$$\eqalign{
G(G^TG)^{-3/2}G^T &= (GG^T)^{-3/2}GG^T \cr
 &= (GG^T)^{-1/2}(GG^T)^{-1}GG^T \cr
 &= (GG^T)^{-1/2} \cr
}$$

Comment: Interesting! What are restrictions on f?

Comment: I don't recall there being any restrictions, as long as the function can be evaluated on the two arguments.